# Why the Microtask queued after chained promises are executed after the first promise resolution ignoring the chained ones?

Tags: javascript, function, promise, callback

I've been experimenting with the `queueMicrotask()` function and I'm not figuring out how callbacks are prioritized when the callbacks are microtasks.
Check out the following code:

```
function tasksAndMicroTasks() {
  const promise = Promise.resolve()

  console.log('#1st call')

  promise
    .then(() => console.log('#3rd call'))
    .then(() => console.log('#4th call'))
    .then(() => console.log('#5th call'))
  
  queueMicrotask(() => console.log(`I'm microtask from the custom Queue`))
  

  console.log('#2nd call')
}
tasksAndMicroTasks()
```

then the output is:

```
#1st call
#2nd call
#3rd call
I'm microtask from the custom Queue
#4th call
#5th call
```

Then I continue with my experiments and try this:

```
function tasksAndMicroTasks() {
  const promise = Promise.resolve()

  console.log('#1st call')

  promise
    .then(() => console.log('#3rd call'))

  promise  
    .then(() => console.log('#4th call'))
    .then(() => console.log('#5th call'))
  
  queueMicrotask(() => console.log(`I'm microtask from the custom Queue`))
  
  console.log('#2nd call')
}
tasksAndMicroTasks()
```

Then the output is:

```
#1st call
#2nd call
#3rd call
#4th call
I'm microtask from the custom Queue
#5th call
```

Therefore my conclusion it is that the "chained promises" are recognized like "second-priority" after the first resolutions and after that the tasks registered using `queueMicrotask(callback)` API.

Can anyone explain me how the Execution Context Stack handle the chained promises and why the chained ones are differents that the first `.then()` registration of callback?

Comment: The `promise` is resolved immediatly. It is stacked into its queue. Then the `.then`, since the parent is already resolved. Other `.then`s are waiting for #3 to resolve. Then there is the custom queue that is added, and the resit is as logical...

Answer (score 4):

A promise returned by `.then()` is resolved with the result of the callback, so it fulfills only *after* the callback has been called. Only at this point, the promise handlers of the chained promise are scheduled on the microtask queue - after all the ones that had initially been scheduled on the already fulfilled promise or by `queueMicrotask`.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that

```
promise.then(fn1).then(fn2);
```

is *not the same* as

```
promise.then(fn1); promise.then(fn2);
```

For the purposes of your experiment, `Promise.resolve().then(fn)` is doing the same thing as `queueMicrotask(fn)`. The Promise is already resolved, so the callback function is queued.

When you chain `.then()` callbacks, you're adding callbacks to the *returned* Promises from the calls to `.then()`. Those Promise objects will not resolve until each `.then()` resolves in sequence. That's the key difference between your first example and your second. In the second one, you add two `.then()` callbacks to the same already-resolved Promise, so they're both queued at that point.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore my conclusion it is that the "chained promises" are
> recognized like "second-priority"

It's not a difference in priority. If you have the code:

```js
promise.then(a).then(b)
```

It's not clear until the first promise resolves whether `.then(b)` will ever be called. The first promise may never resolve.

Therefore `.then(b)` can't be added to the microtask queue immediately, because it may never need to ever be added to the microtask queue.